# How long does redux state persist in memory in react native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, redux

I am trying to understand how to manage redux state in my react-native app. In particular, I am trying to work out what happens when my app is minimized or the device is turned off.

With this knowledge I can then work out best how to persist state, and prepare for any illegal states that may arise from the redux state being reset.

Is it a fair assumption to make that if the redux state is reset, the entire app itself will restart (and therefore any initialization of the redux store will be called again?).

Answer (score 2):

> Is it a fair assumption to make that if the redux state is reset, the entire app itself will restart

This assumption is not true, however the inverse is. The redux state can be reset during runtime if there is code to do it via a reset action or otherwise.

However if the app is shut down, and the code re-runs it will be loaded with your default redux state.

[AsyncStorage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html) (in native) / localstorage for web, is often used in conjunction with redux in order to persist state across app crashes / browser sessions.

You can set AsyncStorage as a strategy for the [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) middleware (or write your own)

Comment: Whoops thanks for catching that - I actually meant is it a fair assumption that if the redux state has been reset, the entire app itself would have been reset. Or, alternatively, are there times where I may lose my redux state without the app being reset, but also without explicitly instructing the app to drop the state in my source code.

The key question I am trying to understand is how mobile devices manage state stored in memory from outside the app itself.