# React-Native Android Redux Store Cleaning Problem

Tags: react-native, redux

I have a react-native app which is working properly for a long time. But after something is happened, i don't know what it is, my app redux store data is not cleaning when i close the app.

Is someone here experiencing same problem? Am i doing something wrong?

By the way, the ios app is working fine. It's only in android.

I didn't share any code with you because everything was working fine before. If you want to take a look into code, just tell me.

Here is a video about my problem: https://streamable.com/wwbsh

---

From another question on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46207962/how-long-does-redux-state-persist-in-memory-in-react-native).

> However if the app is shut down, and the code re-runs it will be
>   loaded with your default redux state.

But my state is not loaded with my defaults.

Thank you.

```
"react": "16.3.1",
"react-redux": "^5.1.1",
"redux": "^4.0.1",
"redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
"redux-persist": "^5.10.0",
"redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
```

Answer (score 0):

After each app launch redux state should be reloaded with the defaults unless you're persisting your state using `redux-persist`

Comment: I think it's not related to `redux-persist`. Im using `react-native-background-geolocation` package and if I disable this package everything works fine. I couldn't figure it out why this is happening but I found this.